# ec2 linux instance root access

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

`vim /etc/sudoers`:

gives warning: vim output is not to a terminal
vim input is not from a terminal

Sudo, yum does not works. Gives error:

`su`: gives error: `standard in must be a tty`

`sudo` : `sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo`

If I try to edit any file directly from gui access then it says no permission.

I want to uninstall xamp from my ec2 linux instance.

I searched for all this issue on web and tried with all solution available. No luck.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: how are you sshing to the box?

Comment: @mindthemonkey: I dont know exactly what you want to know, but I am using WinSCP GUI and terminal inside it for processing!

Comment: i'm curious, why are you using a gui instead of a typical command line via ssh? how did you get xamp on there, and why not just terminate the instance instead of trying to uninstall xamp? is this a production machine? what have you done out of the ordinary such that vim and su don't work?

Comment: @DrewKhoury: Terminating machine? I could not do. I have been given it from my guide to show the work.

Comment: what guide? that comment doesn't make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinSCP has probably not allocated a TTY for the ssh connection and it's simple terminal probably doesn't support much of the functionality anyway

Try connecting with [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) and running the commands there.